# How to get data from database by using $query->result() in codeigniter without foreach loop?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have just started using CodeIgniter and want to get data from database using `$query->result()`, but without a `foreach` loop. Here is my current code:

```
   $this->db->select('m_name');
   $query1 = $this->db->get("marchant_details",1);
   $rows1 = $query1->result();
```

However, I don't want to use a `foreach` loop like this, to retrieve the data:

```
   foreach($query1->result() as $rows1)
   {
       $name[] = $rows1->m_name;
   }
```

Can anyone offer an alternative solution?

Comment: i suppose do you want to take only the first result?

Comment: If you are limiting the SQL query, and fetching the first row only, why did you use a loop to create a one-index `$name` array?

Comment: I see you want the first result only. Use `row()` from http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html

Comment: I've updated my answer, I think one point is not considered in the answers.

Answer (score 4):

I just did a quick search. I'm going to sleep, but can you try something like this:

```
$query->result_array();
```

If it doesn't work, I'll check tomorrow.

source: [user-guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html) Maybe it will come handy.

Answer (score 2):

**There are two assumptions:** either I misunderstood the question *or* the others did.

**The point:** by passing `1` as second parameter to `$this->db->get();` method, it sets `LIMIT 1` to the query and you'll get only `1` row as result.

**So, why should you need to use a loop on a single row db result?**

If you use `$query->result();` the result would be something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [m_name] => Foo
        )

)
```

To get the `m_name` value you can do the following:

```
$result = $query->result();
echo $result[0]->m_name;
```

By any reason, if you need a numeric array contains the value (as you did it in your loop) you can simply do it by `$name[] = $result[0]->m_name;`.

And if you use `$query->result_array();` the result would be something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [m_name] => Foo
        )

)
```

To get the `m_name` value you can do the following:

```
$result = $query->result_array();
echo $result[0]['m_name'];
```

---

**But** if you stop limiting the query, there are multiple rows in your query result, you can use `rows1 = $query1->result_array();` instead. and `array_map()` to manipulate the elements of the given array:

```
$rows1 = $query1->result_array();

// `$row1` will be something like this:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [m_name] => Foo
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [m_name] => Bar
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [m_name] => Baz
        )

)
```

Use `array_map()` to manipulate the result array:

```
function getName($array) {
    return $array['m_name'];
}

$array = array_map("getName", $rows1);

print_r($array);
```

If you are using PHP v5.3+ you do the following:

```
$array = array_map(function($array) {
    return $array['m_name'];
}, $rows1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well there is the official page in the [CodeIgniter User Guide for generating DB query results](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html) depicting variations like

```
$row = $query->first_row()
$row = $query->last_row()
$row = $query->next_row()
$row = $query->previous_row()
```

If you work with CodeIgniter, its charm is that it effectively quite nicely documented.

I would assume you can go further down the abstraction layers if that's what you want, respectively you can not use the DB class but the class of your choice as custom library or whatever.

Why then are you not happy with the given possibilities, respectively how do you want to generate your query results?

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this

```
$data=array();    
$this->db->select('m_name');
$query1 = $this->db->get("marchant_details",1);
$data['name'] = $query1->result_array();
return $data;
```

and for more information

```
result_array();  // For multiple rows
row_array();     // For one row
```